# How to disable column with expandable button in Ui-grid?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am wondering how can I disable the button that gets added in first column when we have `ui-grid-expandable` as our table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns our it was pretty easy. Just overwrite some of the css:

```
.ui-grid-expandable-buttons-cell,.ui-grid-pinned-container.ui-grid-pinned-container-left {
  display:none;
}

.ui-grid-header-canvas{
  height: 50px !important; // SET THIS FOR THE HEIGHT OF THE HEADER ROW
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove/hide grouping expand icon then the shortest way to do is

```
treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
showTreeRowHeader: false,
```

Add this code in your ui-grid options

**Edit** `treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,` is useful for those who want to hide expandable button on page load and show when data is loaded.

Comment: Crisp!... Actually this one line is enough... _showTreeRowHeader: false_

Comment: @VKGS `treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,` is useful for those who want to hide expandable button on page load and show when data is loaded.